# GitHub font alignment issue: extra spaces in source code viewer

Tags: git, github

When viewing my source code files on GitHub, I'm noticing occasional extra spaces being displayed which are not present in the source file (and are also not visible in raw display mode). I've double checked to make sure that I've not used tabs by mistake either.

An example: in [this file, the `char` in line 281 and the `int` in line 282 should align](https://github.com/Time0o/TUD_system_programming_lab/blob/devel/exercise2/src/main.c#L281-L282) but for me there is an extra space in line 282 so the i in `int` aligns with the h in `char`. I'm using Firefox 61.0.2 on Arch Linux, I have not verified this with another browser yet. The displayed font is definitely monospace.

A quick internet search didn't yield anything and I'm not sure if this is actually a GitHub bug or some browser related issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Firefox, Chrome and Edge it aligns perfectly. I'm on Windows 10 64-bit.

[image: Alignment source code]

That said I don't see why you did not more research yourself. Firstly I would've tested it in more browsers. Then I would've searched through the source code of the page itself. Is there really an extra space or is it a style issue? Which css class or tag is used?

If you are convinced this is a github issue please share it with Isaac on github. You can open an issue right here: https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues

Comment: I've just installed Google Chrome and there the issue is indeed not present. My webdesign knowledge is very limited so I'm not sure if I could get much out of the source code. I had just assumed that this might be a well known issue which I just did not manage to find.

Comment: Try updating your FF to the latest version. Maybe it's a quirk. On Windows there is no problem with it so I can't reproduce.